# Carousel of image links that works with JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, jquery-mobile

Can anyone direct me to some code where I can get a neat looking carousel of images which are also links that works with jqm. If I have an option to affect the direction in scrolls something to indicate where I have reached in the carousel that would be great. A JavaScript solution I think will be most ideal. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for a full featured solution or a tutorial to follow. There is a [tutorial here](http://www.crosscode.co.uk/jquery/jquery-carousel-tutorial/) that takes you through the steps to build a simple carousel using jQuery and Javascript. There are hundreds of full featured one's (without tutorial) if you have a search around.

Comment: A plugin should do fine a responsive one would be excellent with touch features. I found one called bxslider but am not sure if it can handle image links